# How to hide show collapse/expand button for only several rows?

Tags: kendo-grid

I am building an app with a grid that has expandable functionality for its rows. But I have 3 types of items inside grid list, and one of these should have detail row functionality. The simple solution is to hide collapse/expand button, but new react wrappers do not expose actual rendering loop of the list.

How can I achieve this?